# understanding flow of RECURSION

Tags: java, recursion

i know the basics of recursion but in the given code i m facing difficulty to understand the flow.
please help me guys...

```
public ArrayList<String> searchFolders(File fo) {

    if (fo.isDirectory()) {

        String internalNames[] = fo.list();



        for (int i = 0; i < internalNames.length; i++) {
            searchFolders(new File(fo.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+ internalNames[i]));
            path = fo.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + internalNames[i];
        }
    }
    if (fo.isFile()) {

        alist.add(fo.toString());


    }


    return alist;
}
```

Comment: Did you try tracking it using debugger?

Comment: Which part that you didn't understand?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116157/understanding-flow-of-recursion) for more help...  I do have to say though that that's one of the worst written recursive directory scanners I've ever seen.

Comment: suppose initially fo is a directory and it contains 8 folders in it.
then the first if condition ll b true nd then the for loop ll b encountered then again searchfolder() ll b called and now suppose there is only a file now so the first if condition ll b false nd so 2nd if ll be encounterd nd the file ll b add to the "alist"  now my question is: will the return statement will run and yes then where will b the controler move????
hope you get my confusion...

Comment: @Alnitak LOL.... Also, Google recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this code is getting all of the contents of a directory and adding them to the global variable `alist`.

You give it a directory.
If it's a file, then it adds its name to the list and the method returns (files can't have subfolders).

If it's a folder, then it lists all of the things in the folder:

```
String internalNames[] = fo.list();
```

And then executes the same search for each item in the folder:

`searchFolders(new File(fo.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+ internalNames[i]));`

So, if the item that you are currently searching is a file (if `fo.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+ internalNames[i]` is the directory of a file), then it just adds the file to the global ArrayList.

Otherwise, if it is a folder, it searches it just like it just searched the folder that it just looks at, and lists all of the files in the folder.

You don't seem to use the variable `path`.

When you return `alist`, you are returning all of the files that you have found in the folder (and its subfolders) so far.
You are not returning folder names, since when `fo.isDirectory()`, you aren't adding its name to `alist`.

[image]

Comment: hi.
i know what is it doing but i am confuse about the flow means how ll b the stack  form and what will b the sequence of execution

Comment: It depends on the order of `internalNames`. If `internalNames` is folders first, then the search will go down all of the levels of the folders until there are no more subfolders, and then it will look at files.

Comment: suppose initially fo have the path of a directory and it contains 8 folders in it. then the first if condition ll b true nd then the for loop ll b encountered then again searchfolder() ll b called and now suppose this time the first internalname is a file. so the first if condition ll b false nd so 2nd if ll be encounterd nd the file ll b add to the "alist" now my question is: will the return statement will run and yes then where will b the controler move???? hope you get my confusion...

Comment: @AshishSIngh Please look at my edit. It might make things clearer. I didn't put any files in it, though.

Comment: @AshishSIngh From StackOverflow Meta: "You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Consider this recursion code as a tree explorer. The searchFolders method will scan for every file/folder present in the current directory and make a list of it, so you can say it's taking all the children from the root node.

After having the list, it will call himself in each child of the root node (to search again for folders and files), and update the path to know where it's searching.

It will stop when it finds all the children nodes (even going down to n levels) which have no folders to explore, but only files.

Answer (score 0):

for short, consider recursion exit:

```
if (fo.isFile()) {

    alist.add(fo.toString());


}
```

when `fo` is a file, add file path to `alist` and exit;
if not true for this recursion exit condition, `fo` is a directory, then recurs till recursion exit---'fo' is a file.

so this `searchFolders` method find every file in the folder and sub folder, return their name as a list!